# Passing classes without creating a supermetaclass in java

Tags: java, junit

I am writing code to test web pages in java and got kind of caught in my own web of abstraction. I use Selenium, but that is not really the issue here.

I do have a set of page objects and a set of junit test classes. But since the web pages have a lot of similar form-elements I did not want to repeat each test over an over again. So I created testfragments which the junit test instantiate. The junit tests basically just call the methods on the fragment classes. 
Now here is my problem: I need to pass the page objects to the fragment classes, so they can act on the webpage. But since each fragment has to be passes a whole lot of different page objects with very different sets of methods, I have trouble to do the abstractions.

What I did to make this work looks to me like very bad code. I created a class inherited by all page objects containing all possible methods that do occur in any page object class.

Is there any better way? Is there any design pattern I have yet to learn?

Comment: The question itself isn't really clear, could you provide a basic example of what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There sure are better ways. You probably want to look in to **encapsulation** and **composition**

You can put behaviour in its own class, and create the different page classes as composites of behaviours.

For example consider PageA and PageB. They both have some common form elements, but also some differences. For example, they share a UserForm.

```
class PageA
{
   Field username
   Field password
   //other fields specific to A
}

class PageB
{
    Field username
    Field password
   //fields that are the userform
   //otherfields specific to B
}
```

You see both A and B share some specific form-fields.

You could but the 'fields that are the userform' in a subclass and make `PageA` and `PageB` contain a `UserForm`.

```
class PageA
{
    UserFormFields userformfields
   //other fields specific to A
}

class PageB
{
    UserFormFields userformfields
   //otherfields specific to B
}
```

Your test can test the UserFormFields with one set of code, because both PageA and PageB have the same UserFormFields. That way you don't have to rewrite this piece of code. The logic for the `UserFormFields` can be in its own class.

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right track. I can put what you call userFormFields into Interfaces and instead of passing the page object as a class type, I pass it as an Interface.

Comment: Now I have to pass the same web-page several times to my fragmentClasses, once for every grouping of fields, but the whole thing is still much clearer